# PHP web service sproc vs. sql query

Tags: php, mysql, post, stored-procedures, service

All:

I am creating a web service using PHP and a stored procedure in mySQL. I'm having a problem getting the sproc CALL to work, while a standard INSERT INTO query works well. Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong? The PHP routine works perfectly if I uncomment the line with the INSERT query and comment out the line with the sproc CALL...thanks

```
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare("call Game.addUser(?,?,?,?)");
 //$stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO Game.activeUsers (playerName, email, zip,     `password`) VALUES(?,?,?,?);');
 $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $playerName, $email, $zip, $pw);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Thank you!

Comment: typo here  $stmt = execute();

Comment: THANKS! It still isn't creating the user in mySQL, after fixing that, but it was a good catch!

Comment: $this->db->commit(); is missing http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php

Comment: is it ok to make "$this->db->autocommit(TRUE);" or is that not equivalent? If its not where would I put the "$this->db->commit();" in the code? I changed the auto commit to true but it still isn't inserting the record...

Comment: should be ok, as long as you are not relying on the results of the previous queries

Comment: is there a way I can trace it to see where its breaking or see errors being generated? I am not seeing an error of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have autocommit set to false, you'll need to manually commit your transactions, and ensure your table engine supports transactions in the first place (InnoDB)

```
// Create new user
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("call Game.addUser(?,?,?,?);");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $playerName, $email, $zip, $password);
$stmt = execute();
$stmt->bind_result($verbose);
$stmt->close();
```

Should probably look more like

```
// Create new user

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("call Game.addUser(?,?,?,?);");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $playerName, $email, $zip, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($verbose);
$this->db->commit();//change here
$stmt->close();
```

NOTE: I haven't put in any error checking for you, so you'll need to enter some. Tends to look like this when working with transactions:

```
if(!$this->db->commit()){
    $this->db->rollback();
}
```

With regards to logging, I would recommend starting [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error-list.php)

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I just substituted those strings to conceal the actual values. Assume those strings are populated with proper values that work. I am certain that piece works. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Okidoki, not a problem :) Time to keep looking!! Unless you solved your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help! I made the change to explicitly commit after the transaction, but still no record in the db. I am working on the logging now so I can see whats happening. I don't see any errors, but that doesn't mean I'm not getting any! Thanks again...

Comment: Here's something we haven't touched on. Your stored procedure! Have you tested it in just a raw command line to make sure it works? I'm just trying to narrow in on where the problem might be. Squirrely little issue this one

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had to travel for my company. My sproc definitely works, even when cutting and pasting directly from the php file. It seems the POST isn't triggering the logic in the file. I have hard coded the sproc call with parameters (not variables) and simplified it to a line that defines the $stmt and a line that does the $stmt->$this->db->execute() and still no record ends up in the db table. Perhaps the main issue is in my createUserForm.html file? Also, do I need HTML headers on the PHP file?

Comment: No worries on travel, honestly I wish mine would let us travel like we need to >.> Have you implemented any logging yet so that we can see where control flow is going?
With regards to your question about HTML headers in the PHP file, the only thing "HTMLish" you need is that first <?php unless you've got non php in the file, then you have to make sure you close it with ?>

Comment: I haven't added the logging as I am a little unsure about exactly what to do. Do I just add "echo "Error:\n";
    print_r(mysql_stmt_error_list($stmt));" after the $stmt->execute(); line? After I do that where do I see the logged errors?

Comment: Lots of ways to handle errors :)
Here's one set of instructions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php   and then your other one using mysqli_stmt_error_list($stmt) should also work. You can also check your HTTP logs for errors, or if you're awesome and on a mac just go to Applications -> Utilities -> Console.

Comment: Had some other findings last night. I think this might stem from Linux or MySQL permissions. Using code that works I pointed it at the DB we've been troubleshooting (without changing the code other than the redirect) and it didn't work. On the logging help, I run the dev on a Mac but my server is an AWS Linux server. Can I still see the errors in my Mac console if the browser is running on the Mac?

Comment: Run your app locally so you can see the errors in the console, use MAMP or something.

Comment: So this was really helpful, thanks! I now have most of it working. There were multiple syntax problems, the most impactful was the lack of double quotes around my method=post line in the HTML file. I can now get it working using an insert query, but when I try to call the stored procedure using the same code/method it doesn't work. No errors anywhere, it just doesn't work. The sproc is effectively just a wrapper around the same insert query that works directly in the PHP code. There is some nuance to calling a sproc versus a regular SQL query that is escaping me. Any advice? Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome, gald to hear! And if you really need to check for syntax errors quickly and easily. If you have the CLI enhanced version of PHP installed, just fire up a command line and run php -l filename.php and it will perform a syntax check and report the errors.

Now, as far as your proc goes, you're saying that a raw insert works, but the sproc doesn't? Can you update your question with that?

Comment: Yes, let me copy the code examples and I'll update the question.